# Powe BI-Line chart-5 single-select slicers of 'Company Name' instead of 1 multi-select slicer

Tags: python, powerbi, visualization, powerquery, data-modeling

I am currently making a line chart comparing multiple company's ESG score trend over several years. I want the user to select 5 companies to compare from 5 different slicers instead of one multi-select slicer.

I want the user to select a single company from one of the 5 slicers which would then populate the line chart. Now i know i can use multi-select in one slicer but that would be difficult to do for a layman as they wouldn't know to press cntrl for multi-select.

So to compare 5 different companies in the line chart, user must select 5 companies individually in 5 different slicers.

How do i accomplish this? Can this even be done? Since in the legend section of the line chart, you can only add one column (Company Name) and one legend would correspond to only one slicer.

Adjusted the interaction between the 5 slicers. Each slicer will be able to interact with only the line chart visual and nothing else, not even the other slicers.

They are part of the same table so i don't think cross filtering should be an issue.

I don't want to do this with just one multi-select slicer but 5 single select slicer of the same 'Company Name' column.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use just the one slicer. In `Slicer settings` > `Selection`: Switch off `Multi-select with CTRL`.
2. Use multiple slicers - **however** each one of those slicers will need to be from a different table. So that would be 5 different tables of the `Company Name`. There is no other way than this for multiple slicers of the same dimension table.

Answer (score 0):

By Selecting the Slicer you can  Ctrl Option to avoid multi-select.

1. Select the Slicer
2. Go to Slicer Format Pane
3. Inside Option > Selection > Toggle Off the "Multi-Select with Ctrl"

hope it help you out.